Stoichiometry of gaseous mixture of CO CO2 and N2
I am confused about the following question which is mostly about reduction of volume in reactions along with stoichiometry and gaseous mixtures. The question is as follows:
200ml of a gaseous mixture containing CO, CO₂, and N₂ on complete combustion in just sufficient amount of O₂ showed contraction of 40mL . When the resulting gases were passed through KOH solution, it reduces by 50%. Calculate Volume ratio
V(CO₂) : V(CO) : V(N₂).
The method used by almost all sources in brief is like,

Assuming volumes of CO, N₂ to be x,y.
Only CO reacts with O₂, so amount of O₂ will be x/2.
Volume of mixture is 200+x/2 (I don't get this).
So volume contraction= 40 = x/2.

∴ x = 80mL.

Considering given 50% volume reduction, and only CO₂ reacts with KOH ,    then doing some algebra,

Volume of CO₂ = 20mL and
Volume of N₂ = 100mL
Giving Ratio of 4:1:5.
Here are the confusions, doubts I have.

In the question, volume reduction is given to be 40mL. What is this reduction of? In general as far as I know, when the gases in product evolves, that causes volume reduction. However, here all three are gases.
Why did we consider the O₂ to be a part of mixture? (Step 3).
If we consider O₂ to be part of mixture, then volume reduction can be understood, as per reaction of

2L CO + 1L O₂ giving only 2L CO and 1L volume reduction.
Is this the reason, or there's something else I'm missing?

The question says "it reduces by 50%". How can I know that here it- refers to the total volume of mixture? And, if O₂ is considered to be part of mixture while calculating volume reduction, why isn't it considered here?

Please help me clear the confusion.

It should lead to simple set of 4 linear equations with 4 variables (volumes of each of gases), given by 4 conditions (mixture volume, contraction, absorption, combustion stoichiometry).


Volume of mixture is 200+x/2 (I don't get this).

$\pu{200 mL}$ of the mixture + $\frac{x}{2}\ \pu{mL}$ of oxygen.

Why did we consider the O₂ to be a part of mixture? (Step 3).

You mix the original mixture with oxygen and then you combust it, what causes after cooling down contraction to the original volumes. As partial volumes of $\ce{N2}$ and original $\ce{CO2}$ remain and the partial volume of $\ce{CO}$ is replaced by the same volume of $\ce{CO2}$. Added $\ce{O2}$ is contained in newly formed $\ce{CO2}$.

The question says "it reduces by 50%". How can I know that here it- refers to the total volume of mixture?

How exactly you imaging such 50% absorption?
$\ce{CO + N2 + CO2(\text{orig)} ->[O2 addition][200 + 40 mL]\\
CO + N2 + CO2(\text{orig)} + O2 ->[combustion][- 40 mL]\\
 CO2(\text{combusted)} + N2 + CO2(\text{orig)}->[absorption][50 \%] N2}$

For convenience, let $x=V_\ce{CO}$, $y=V_\ce{N2}$, $z=V_\ce{CO2}$, $t=V_\ce{O2}$
If we consider the original mixture, it does not get contracted by combustion, as the total molar amount remains the same. So it must include oxygen and its volume is equal to the contraction volume.
Then
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Mixture volume} & x+y+z=\pu{200 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Contraction} & t=\pu{40 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Absorption} & x+z=\dfrac{x+y+z}{2} \\
\hline
\text{Stoichiometry} & x=2t \\
\hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Mixture volume} & x+y+z=\pu{200 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Contraction} & t=\pu{40 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Absorption} & x+z=y \\
\hline
\text{Stoichiometry} & x=\pu{80 mL} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Mixture volume} & y+z=\pu{120 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Contraction} & t=\pu{40 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Absorption} & \pu{80 mL} + z=y \\
\hline
\text{Stoichiometry} & x=\pu{80 mL} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Mixture volume} & y+z=\pu{120 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Contraction} & t=\pu{40 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Absorption} & \pu{80 mL} +(\pu{120 mL - y})=y \\
\hline
\text{Stoichiometry} & x=\pu{80 mL} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Mixture volume} & z=\pu{20 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Contraction} & t=\pu{40 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Absorption} & y = \pu{100 mL} \\
\hline
\text{Stoichiometry} & x=\pu{80 mL} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$V_\ce{CO} : V_\ce{N2} : V_\ce{CO2}$ = 4 : 5 : 1

The question harbors silliness! CO+ 1/2O2 = CO2. If no O2 is present in the original mix and O2 is metered in to just oxidize the CO to CO2 there will be no change in volume hence no problem for the first question The amount of O2 added gives the CO present. The removal of CO2 by the KOH gives total CO2 and N2. If the original mix contained the exact stoichiometric amount of O2 and CO, then both had to be known quantities and the question is moot. If excess O2 is needed to guarantee oxidation then an additional step is needed to remove excess O2, but the original conditions say no O2. So what was in the container in the first place and what was the volume. The question is was the O2 present or was the O2 metered in.
